# How to get the date object

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

My value contains "08.07.1987", how to retrieve the date object for this string. new Date(val) gives correct date object values only for the string value that contains "/" format. can any one let me know hot to create date object for the values which contains "." or "-". in its format.

Comment: Are you using a jquery datepicker on your page somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

How about just adjusting the string to suit your needs?

```
var date1 = new Date("08.07.1987".replace('.','/'));
var date2 = new Date("08-07-1987".replace('-','/'));
```

You will need to be careful when asking Javascript to interpret a date in this format. As you can probably imagine, a date listed as "08.07.1987" doesn't really specify whether it's August 7th or July 8th.

In general, your best bet will be to specify a date format and parse accordingly.

Comment: Works in chrome, but I can't confirm elsewhere. Regardless, the mm/dd ambiguity always leaves me feeling a little unclean about trying to infer date formats...

Comment: @VaralakshmiSeetharaman can you confirm what browser it doesn't work in?

Answer (score 1):

you have to split the string into tokens for month date and year and then create it using JS Date API.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date="08.07.1987";
var newDate = date.replace(/(\.|-)/g,"/"));
var dateObject = new Date(newDate);
```

Comment: You *are* aware that handing a machine a date in ##.##.#### format doesn't really clarify whether said date begins with mm.dd or dd.mm, right?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the delimiters?

```
  var dateStr = "08.07.1987",
      dateObj = new Date(dateStr.replace(/[-.]/g,"/"));
```

Of course you can encapsulate that in a function if need be...

Comment: Your question started with the premise that using `/` would work and you just wanted to know how to deal with full stops or hyphens, so that's what I've covered in my answer. If you'd mentioned up front what format you wanted I would've taken that into account, but I don't have time to update my answer now - have a look at DmitryB's answer...

Answer (score 0):

try this    `new Date("08.07.1987".replace('.','/','g'));`  tested on firefox only